# Separate VoIP traffic from Data traffic on a computer that has a softphone

Tags: networking, router, voip

I have been entrusted recently with a task that seems a bit more complicated than I initially thought.

I would have asked Google, but I can't quite formulate the right question using just a few words.

So let me explain in just a few words what is all about:

My company wants to physically separate VoIP traffic from Data traffic, for this they have bought a dark fiber connection, which connects directly into our SIP server at a remote location.

All good until here, just connect all the hardphones to dark fiber.

The problem is with softphones. I want to separate the Data Traffic from VoIP traffic, meaning that when the guy calls and browses the internet, both at the same time, I want the VoIP traffic to go through dark fiber directly into our SIP server and Data traffic to go through our network.

Any suggestions on how to do that and at the same time keep the hardware to a minimum? Not because of the money but rather because of the VoIP quality, money is not an issue.

Comment: Your network guys should be able to help... The VoIP software should connect over a port or protocol of some sort. They could write some routes into your network switches or routers so send the VoIP packets to your dark fibre and everything else to the Internet gateway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only the ports which SIP users (typically 5060 and 5061) will need to be routed though the switches to the dark fiber, but also the RTP voice streams which can be on any ports between 10000 - 20000 . Your voice system administrator can advise what ports were assigned for RTP.

And, to reward those of us who spend our time to provide answers, please click the checkmark at the left of the answer which works for you, so they gain more powers (such as Kryptonite Immunity and the ability to edit posts without approval).

Comment: Thank you, both to you and @Big Chris, I will implement a port based VLAN.

I can't upvote Big Chris's post nor yours due to insufficient points or something, but I'm trully gratefull for your help.

Thank you! x1000

Comment: The check mark is an up vote. Editing the questions of other new folks is a path to acquiring enough points to gain more privilege. I up voted Big Chris for you.

Comment: Hello, if you have the same problem as I described above, try to look into "ip helper" command on a CISCO router or layer 3 switch. Best of luck!